# Power Query: Extract substring containing quotation marks from a long string with many quotation marks inside

Tags: escaping, powerbi, powerquery, m

```
{"c": "4343434", "d": "m", "k": "+la+la", "l": "40990", "m": "b", "n": "o",
"p": "{adposition}", "s": "b", "dm": "{devicemodel}", "adc": "{creative}", 
"adg": "454554545454", "src": "hahahah45", "tid": "kwd-utututututu", 
"utm_term": "+ka +ka", "utm_medium": "cpc"}
```

I am trying to extract the section `"s":"b"` into a new column in a Power Query query. I know this comes down to escaping and I've read the official documentation of the M formula language but I just don't get how to extract this using the text formulas only. How can I do this?

Comment: What are the rules for extracting the piece you want? Everything between `"{adposition}", ` and  `"{devicemodel}"`?

Comment: @alexisolson - Hi, not really, I only need what s is, in this case s is b, so basically if I could get "s": "b" as a result that would be good enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ShiYang has key function needed.

If you have a table where a column called `Text` where each row has text like in your post, then you can write a custom column that extracts the value belonging to `s` using the following formula:

```
= Json.Document([Text])[s]
```

This takes the text in column `[Text]` and reads it as JSON and extracts the `s` component.

---

The full step code looks like this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Preveious Step", "Custom", each Json.Document([Text])[s])
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. You are a life saver! You really taught me something here, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Json.Document` to parse Json。

```
let
    Source = "{""c"": ""4343434"", ""d"": ""m"", ""k"": ""+la+la"", ""l"": ""40990"", ""m"": ""b"", ""n"": ""o"", ""p"": ""{adposition}"", ""s"": ""b"", ""dm"": ""{devicemodel}"", ""adc"": ""{creative}"", ""adg"": ""454554545454"", ""src"": ""hahahah45"", ""tid"": ""kwd-utututututu"", ""utm_term"": ""+ka +ka"", ""utm_medium"": ""cpc""}",
    Result = Json.Document(Source)[s]
in
    Result
```

Comment: this looks great but I need this as a new column in an existing query, there's more things going on in the query than just extracting this, it should be just one of the steps resulting in a new column. Thanks for your last response though!